# Plugin not displaying function on page where shortcode is present

Tags: wordpress

This is a plugin I'm currently developing, it's function is to display a CSV file stored in the plugin directory, as an HTML table; The reason I'm writing this manually rather than using one of the many already existing plugins which perform a similar task is; I need to be able to use the html output for another script's functions that will be executed later, rather than just displaying this data.

The shortcode is functioning because it isn't visible on the page, however nothing else appears on the page.

As far as I know the csv file I'm using to test this plugin isn't corrupted, can be opened.

This is the content of Book1.csv:

```
test1,test2,test3
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
13,14,15
```

---

```
<?php

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            Image
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Price
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php

add_shortcode( "csv", "open_csv_file");

function open_csv_file() {

$handle = fopen("Book1.csv", "r");



 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE):
 }

 ?>

 <?php

    <tr>
        <td><?= $data[1] ?></td>
        <td><?= $data[2] ?></td>
        <td>$<?= number_format($data[7], 2) ?></td>
    </tr>
 endwhile;
}
    </tbody>
</table>

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some errors in your code, first you are not getting any output because

- } for function is closed in wrong place
- short tags <?= may not work if it is disabled in configuration

The following may work,

```
<?php
add_shortcode( "csv", "open_csv_file");

function open_csv_file() {
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>
            Image
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Price
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php
$handle = fopen("Book1.csv", "r");



 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE):

 ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data[1]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data[2]; ?></td>
        <td>$<?php echo number_format($data[7], 2); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
 endwhile;

?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Hello, when I try and activate the plugin with your revised code, I get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in csv2.php on line 44

;Line 44 is the <tr> between <?php and <td><?php echo $data[1]; ?></td>